# Висит apache, ресурсов хватает

Tags: apache, httpd, сервер

Всем привет.

В последнее время заметил, что когда достигается определенное число процессов httpd, то апач начинает висеть. Ресурсов хватает, апач не падает. Просто висит. Никаких изменений в конфигурации не делал (только после появления проблемы увеличил лимиты, в итоге процессов увеличилось, но висит так же).

Перезагружал и сам апач, и весь сервер.

В чем же может быть дело?

Все на CentOS 5.

Comment: Попробуйте отключить keepalive

Comment: А в логах-то что, кто ходит, зачем, может какие запросы повисают.Ну и что там происходит - начиная с ab.

Comment: Я просто намудрил с асинхронными запросами к серверу. их создавалось за секунду около 100